# What is the determinant of a 0x0 matrix

Tags: determinant

I'm attempting to compute the value of an arbitrarily large matrix (order $n$). In simplifying the determinant, I was able to express its value in terms of the determinants of smaller matrices of the same form. Specifically,

$$
D_n = 2 \cos \theta D_{n-1} - D_{n-2},
$$

where $D_n$ is the determinant of the original order $n$ matrix. The form of the original matrix isn't critical to this question (just the recursive relationship), but if you're curious

$$
D_n = \begin{vmatrix}
    \cos \theta & 1             & 0             & 0             &        &               & 0             \\
    1           & 2 \cos \theta & 1             & 0             & \dots  & \dots         & 0             \\
    0           & 1             & 2 \cos \theta & 1             &        &               & 0             \\
    0           & 0             & 1             & 2 \cos \theta &        &               & 0             \\
                &               & \vdots        &               & \ddots &               & \vdots        \\
                &               & \vdots        &               &        & 2 \cos \theta & 1             \\
    0           & 0             & 0             & 0             & \dots  & 1             & 2 \cos \theta \\
\end{vmatrix}.
$$

I've defined $D_{n-1}$ in terms of $D_n$ by removing the last row and column from $D_n$.

My question is: where does this recursive relationship end? In Mathematical Methods in the Physical Sciences by boas, section 3.3, Boas states:

> The value of det A if A is a 1 by 1 matrix is just the value of the single element

So, $D_1=\cos\theta$.

But, what about the 0x0 matrix $D_0$? Is this just 0? Is it defined at all?

Comment: The determinant of a $0\times 0$ matrix is usually considered to be equal to $1$.

Comment: If you take determinant to be defined as the “product” of eigenvalues, then $0\times0$ matrix determinant is going to be an empty product; conventionally, that’s taken as equal to $1$.

Comment: @JMoravitz yes that does. Thanks for pointing that out.